# Implicit wait in robot class. Is it possible?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am automating an application where the robot class first click on cancel button and then it clicks on a menu item and then it clicks on a sub menu item. After clicking the sub menu it has to wait(time is unknown), because it loads an environment,  and then it clicks on a button. So is there any way so that i can wait for that particular time and it has to exit when the task is finished. It should not wait more or less.

I am providing my code please help me in implementing this code.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChangeAsst {



public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {


    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\PeopleSoft\\Change Assistant\\changeassistant.exe");

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(2000);
    System.out.println(robot.isAutoWaitForIdle());

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

    /* 
     * this is where i want to implement the code so that it should wait for that particular time (it should not wait more or less)
     * When environment loading is done it should exit from this and go to next line of code. 
     * 
     * I can use here as :
     * robot.delay(10000);
     *  but it will wait for 10 seconds, even if loading is done in 3rd seconds also.
     */


    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.delay(300);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT); 
    robot.delay(5000);

    System.out.println(robot.isAutoWaitForIdle());



}

}
```

Comment: In your case, no.  What I've done before used a JNI integration and checked for the state of the Window I've been interacting with, waiting for a certain component(s) to become available...

Comment: @MadProgrammer can u please share the code or a part of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not, it's part of a closed software package that I no longer have access to...

Comment: Essentially, it boild down to [FindWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions